# Project template for Visual Studio 2015

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core

I am trying to create a project template for Visual Studio 2015. I created a ASP.NET 5 class library (under the web section of Visual studio 2015) and used the option File->Export template. When I tried to create project using the exported template, only the .xproj file gets created. The files within the template and the dependencies are not getting added. But the same procedure works fine for normal class library project. 
Am I missing something.?

Comment: Hey Anandha could you please accept @Bebben's answer?  It worked for me, and judging by the up votes it's a generally accepted answer.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I found the way to do this. Open up the zipfile and edit the .vstemplate file. The line that is missing is

```
<CreateInPlace>true</CreateInPlace>
```

This line goes between

```
<TemplateData></TemplateData>
```

This solves the problem for .NET Core 1.0.1 Tooling Preview 2, VS2015 Update 3.

Comment: Worked perfectly for me .NET Core 1.0.1 etc. Thanks!!

Comment: This is still the answer for VS2017.  Wish this got the check.

Answer (score 3):

In order to solve this, I had to extract the output zipfile, and edit the `.vstemplate` file.

Removing the `TargetFileName` attribute from the `<Project>` element under `<TemplateContent>` worked, and the new `.xproj` file was correctly named.

The relevant part of the `.vstemplate` file looked like this:

```
<TemplateContent>
  <Project TargetFileName="MyProject.xproj" File="MyProject.xproj" ReplaceParameters="true">
```

And I changed it to:

```
<TemplateContent>
  <Project File="MyProject.xproj" ReplaceParameters="true">
```

The inspiration for this came from looking at [the ASP.NET 5 project templates](https://github.com/aspnet/Templates), and specifically [the empty web's `.vstemplate` file](https://github.com/aspnet/Templates/blob/dev/src/BaseTemplates/EmptyWeb.vstemplate).

Comment: This did not work for me. Visual Studio 2015 Update 2