# VS exported template does not work with new project

Tags: visual-studio, templates, asp.net-core, project, asp.net5

I have exported the following working project as a VS template, which uses ASP.NET 5 RC1 :

https://github.com/mohasi/vs.spa.template

When I create a new project using it I get almost nothing :

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I have the same issue. Were you ever able to resolve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Project template for Visual Studio 2015](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33886230/project-template-for-visual-studio-2015)