# Custom ASP.NET Core Template not scaffolding with any files in the project

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, templates, asp.net-core

I've spent a number of hours today setting up a project template for all my near-future projects with the ASP.NET, Angular 2, auto transpiling gulp tasks for sass and ts, and the login system scaffolding for FB, Google, and Twitter.

I went through VS2015's Export Template wizard, and made my custom template; however, when I go to New->Project and select the template I made no files are in the solution after creation. What am I doing wrong?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I found this post this morning: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36720652/vs-exported-template-does-not-work-with-new-project?rq=1

I tried adding my template to c# and to .Net Core directories. Neither of them fixed anything.

Comment: I am having the same exact issue and I can't find any help online.  I'm starting to wonder if this is even possible for ASP.NET Core

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Project template for Visual Studio 2015](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33886230/project-template-for-visual-studio-2015)