# Can't create ASP.Net Core project from exported template. Project contains no files

Tags: visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core

Using Visual Studio 2015 Update 2

Steps to reproduce:

1. Create new ASP.NET Core Web Application (.Net Core)
2. File -> Export
   Template.
3. Choose to Automatically import the template into Visual
   Studio
4. Restart Visual Studio
5. File -> New -> Project
6. The new template
   should be imported under .NET Core. Select it and click "OK"

After the project is created, Solution Explorer will not contain any files. There is only virtual folders for References and Dependencies.

This method works with ASP.NET 4.6 projects.

I found [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33886230/project-template-for-visual-studio-2015) which suggested modifying the .vstemplate file, but it did not work for me.

Comment: I am having the same exact issues but my framework is 4.6.1