# How to create a Visual Studio 2015 project template for NET Core?

Tags: .net, templates, visual-studio-2015, .net-core

I want to create a seed project for VS 2015 with the basic setup for Angular2 on ASP.NET Core, so I would like to make it as a template.

On the New Project window, under Extensibility I have a C# Project Template, but it targets the Full .NET Framework.

I also tried exporting a .NET Core sample project as template, but it doesn't work with .NET Core either. When I select it as the template for the new project, it as an empty project on VS with a 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object' error on my Error List window.

Is there any other way to create a template for .NET Core?

Comment: I have the same issue.  It generates an empty project.

Comment: Same issue here. I've exported an existing .NET Core project, but when I use it as a template, I get the same error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Project template for Visual Studio 2015](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33886230/project-template-for-visual-studio-2015)

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to just move the comment that fixed my problem into the answers.  Thanks to @Paul Hiles in the comments above for the following reference: [Project template for Visual Studio 2015](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33886230/project-template-for-visual-studio-2015)

While I've been unable to make it work in a multi-solution template.  It works perfectly for a single .NET Core project template.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the dotnet cli (command-line interface) tool to create this .NET core web projects. It is cross-platform so you can use it in Mac or Linux as well.

Create the dir/folder for the project. In the console, type the following.

```
folder-name>dotnet new -t web
```

Then open the project in VS Code by typing the following:

```
folder-name>code .
```

That is with a period in the end and hit enter.