# Create a .NET Core template in visual studio

Tags: c#, templates, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core

When I make a template from a .NET Core console application and create a new project with the just made template it always seems to be empty. Is the template functionality simple not working for .NET Core projects yet?

My result:

[image: solutionExplorer]

ErrorList:

[image]

**EDIT:**
Same result with a .NET Core Class Library

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33886230/project-template-for-visual-studio-2015/39718930#39718930

Comment: Is this happening just for .Net Core applications or all other projects targeting .NET v4.6.1 as well?
What happens if you create a .NET Core application using console only? E.g. following this tutorial: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/core/tutorials/using-on-macos

Comment: @Venky The answer on the other post was the correct one. I can use my template now :) Thx!

Comment: great.  Can you tell me which answer worked for you. Because in the other post it was not marked as answer. So it's not useful for other people having same problem.  If you tell me the answer.. I will post it here and you can mark it as answer.. Then it would be helpful for others.

Comment: @Venky The solution for me was addind `<CreateInPlace>true</CreateInPlace>` to the `TemplateData` tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this. Open up the zipfile and edit the .vstemplate file. The line that is missing is

```
<CreateInPlace>true</CreateInPlace>
This line goes between

<TemplateData></TemplateData>
```

This solves the problem for .NET Core 1.0.1 Tooling Preview 2, VS2015 Update 3.

Comment: Worked for my Core 2.0 project! Kinda stupid that this is still not properly implemented by default for core projects...