# Visual studio 2015 ASP.Core project template

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, asp.net-core, project-template

Im trying to create a project template that I can reuse for multiple projects. I've tried exporting the template and making it a vsix.

It doesn't matter what I do, whenever I use that template, it does not load any files, references etc.

Is there any documentation or does anyone know how to make a template for ASP.core?

EDIT:
I followed the instructions in the first link you gave me, but it still doesn't work. I don't get all the files I made in my template. Any solutions?

[image: My project]

[image]

Comment: the current tooling is temporary, .xproj and project.json will be going away and ideas from it will be incorporated in .csproj project system. I would wait until then to try to make templates

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/ligershark/side-waffle/wiki/How-to-create-templates-for-ASP.NET-Core

Something like this? I just entered `"ASP.core vsix template"` in Google...

There are also ASP.NET Core Template Packs: https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/31a3eab5-e62b-4030-9226-b5e4c9e1ffb5
http://vsixgallery.com/extension/ae9d6285-3f2a-4cbe-9021-82eb4d8b8c74/

Answer (score 0):

I found the following answer to be helpful when I was running into a similar issue with a NET Core project template: [Project template for Visual Studio 2015](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33886230/project-template-for-visual-studio-2015)

The suggestion to add

```
<CreateInPlace>true</CreateInPlace>
```

in between the tag for

```
<TemplateData></TemplateData>
```

fixed it for me; otherwise, I would simply end up with an empty project.