# Missing folders in custom Visual Studio project template

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-templates

I'm going to create a custom Visual Studio project template to avoid repeating extra work of common configuration tasks for an ASP.NET Core project like adding EntityFramework with MySQL support. So I created a new sample project for this and did an export using *Project > Export template*.

But when I create a new project based on my custom template, all folders like `Controllers` or `Views` are missing. Only `wwwroot` exists. I inspected the `.vstemplate` file, which seems to adding the folders correctly

```
  <Folder Name="wwwroot" TargetFolderName="wwwroot" />
  <Folder Name="Controllers" TargetFolderName="Controllers">
```

So it's not understandable for me, that `wwwroot` is created, but `Controllers` not, since they're using the exactly same directive.

The full VS template file:

```
<VSTemplate Version="3.0.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/vstemplate/2005" Type="Project">
  <TemplateData>
    <Name>AspNetCoreMySQL</Name>
    <Description>Test</Description>
    <ProjectType>CSharp</ProjectType>
    <ProjectSubType>
    </ProjectSubType>
    <SortOrder>1000</SortOrder>
    <CreateNewFolder>true</CreateNewFolder>
    <DefaultName>AspNetCoreMySQL</DefaultName>
    <ProvideDefaultName>true</ProvideDefaultName>
    <LocationField>Enabled</LocationField>
    <EnableLocationBrowseButton>true</EnableLocationBrowseButton>
    <Icon>__TemplateIcon.ico</Icon>
  </TemplateData>
  <TemplateContent>
    <Project TargetFileName="AspNetCoreMySQL.csproj" File="AspNetCoreMySQL.csproj" ReplaceParameters="true">
      <Folder Name="Properties" TargetFolderName="Properties">
        <ProjectItem ReplaceParameters="true" TargetFileName="launchSettings.json">launchSettings.json</ProjectItem>
      </Folder>
      <Folder Name="wwwroot" TargetFolderName="wwwroot" />
      <Folder Name="Controllers" TargetFolderName="Controllers">
        <ProjectItem ReplaceParameters="true" TargetFileName="PageController.cs">PageController.cs</ProjectItem>
      </Folder>
      <ProjectItem ReplaceParameters="true" TargetFileName="Program.cs">Program.cs</ProjectItem>
      <ProjectItem ReplaceParameters="true" TargetFileName="ScaffoldingReadMe.txt">ScaffoldingReadMe.txt</ProjectItem>
      <ProjectItem ReplaceParameters="true" TargetFileName="Startup.cs">Startup.cs</ProjectItem>
    </Project>
  </TemplateContent>
</VSTemplate>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This nice [workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39718930/5112433) is actual for Visual Studio 2017. Edit `.vstemplate` and add:

```
<CreateInPlace>true</CreateInPlace>
```

inside:

```
<TemplateData>...</TemplateData>
```

Don't forget to copy updated ZIP file to:

```
Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Templates\ProjectTemplates\
```

This should reload the template in VS. Please pay attention to @Lion comment below if you have troubles with reloading.

Comment: That works, **BUT** updating templates is a real mess in Visual Studio: My zip file in `Documents/Visual Studio 2017/Templates/ProjectTemplates` is completely ignored. Instead, the extracted folder in `C:\Users\Daniel\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio\15.0_51c08c96\ProjectTemplatesCache` is used. So I've to update it there or delete the sub-folder for the template first. Such stupid behaviour cause a lot of trouble to make simple things work... But thanks for your solution, it works when you clear the cache first :)